# grpcio issue on MAC M1

Tags: mac, m1

Не могу установить/обновить grpcio, которая нужна для другой библиотеки.  Перепробовал все что угодно.

что стоит:

```
Python 3.9.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Feb  1 2022, 21:27:43)
[Clang 11.1.0 ] on darwin
```

Comment: Ну так что конкретно перепробовали-то и почему конкретно не получилось-то?

Comment: Ну и вообще https://github.com/pietrodn/grpcio-mac-arm-build

Comment: pip install wheels.yml
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheels.yml (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheels.yml

Comment: пробовал разные советы, которые гуглятся на эту тему. например: export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=1
export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1

Comment: хе..... в общем, устанавливая другой пакет, он подтянул нужные зависимости и все получилось:     pip install cython
brew install hdf5
brew install c-blosc
export HDF5_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5 
export BLOSC_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/c-blosc

Answer (score 0):

проблему можно закрыть.  Действительно, все возможные советы не работали. Для других целей мне нужно было поставить tables, были тоже ошибки. нашел решение, которое помогло поставить tables, и о чудо, после сразу же без проблем стало grpcio:

pip install cython
brew install hdf5
brew install c-blosc
export HDF5_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5
export BLOSC_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/c-blosc

после этого
pip inttall tables завершилось без ошибки,
pip install grcpio также завершилось без ошибки.